# set format in DrawText win32 function

Tags: c#, winapi

When I draw text by DrawText function of Win32 API
Is there a way to determine which font will be used, or determine the font size, or bold, or italic?
PS I write in C#

Comment: `DrawText()` will use the currently selected font in the device context you pass. You would have to create the appropriate `HFONT` and use `SelectObject()` to associate it with your `HDC` (and save the returned handle to reinstate it when you're finished), which can be tedious. Is there any reason you're using Win32 instead of the managed APIs?

Comment: DrawString of winForms use in points for font size, and I want to use for small scale units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> The DrawText function uses the device context's selected font, text color, and background color to draw the text.

Which means that you can obtain current font handle from the device context, and then obtain [`LOGFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which provides you details about the font, that you requested.

Since API is using currently selected font, to change it you need to have the new font handle available (you typically pre-create it, or otherwise get `HFONT` font handle using e.g. [`CreateFont`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `CreateFontIndirect` API). Then prior to calling `DrawText` you replace current selected font with your own using `SelectObject` and once you are done you place the orignial font back with another `SelectObject` call.